# How to find linearly independent columns in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a general square matrix $A$, how do I find which columns are linearly dependent? When I say linear independent I mean not linearly dependent with any other column or any combination of other columns in the matrix.

For example:

\begin{matrix}
  0 & -2 & 1 \\
  0 & -4 & 2 \\
  1 & -2 & 1
 \end{matrix}

In this matrix we know that column 1 is linear independent and columns 2 and 3 are dependent.

I want something that always works, and I already have the SVD and QR decomposition implemented in Java and I hope one or both of them can help me solving this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not delete a question that has been answered, only to repost the very same question.

Comment: It isn't the same question. My first question was poorly asked as you said. Your answer didn't answer this question, it simply solved the equation system.

Comment: More importantly, @amWhy: how do I solve this?

Comment: Sorry @amWhy but you said the question was ill-formed and others said so as well. I appreciate your efforts but as said your answer wasn't answering this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m\geq n$, compute the (economy) QR factorisation. This gives
$$
A = QR, \quad R\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}.
$$
Now if $\mathrm{rank}(A)<n$, the upper triangular matrix $R$ has a staircase profile with some of the "steps" of the staircase over more than one column. Select column indices $j_1,\ldots,j_k$ such that if you remove these columns from $R$, you obtain a nonsingular upper triangular matrix (you can consider it as making each step of the staircase of length 1). The columns $j_1,\ldots,j_k$ can be expressed as linear combination of the remaining columns.

Example: The red columns indicate the columns which are linear combinations of the others.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\times & \times & \color{red}\times & \times & \color{red}\times & \color{red}\times \\
0      & \times & \color{red}\times & \times & \color{red}\times & \color{red}\times \\
0      & 0      & \color{red}0      & \times & \color{red}\times & \color{red}\times
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Example: For the given matrix from the question, the QR factorisation is:

```
Q =

         0   -0.4472   -0.8944
         0   -0.8944    0.4472
   -1.0000         0         0

R =

   -1.0000    2.0000   -1.0000
         0    4.4721   -2.2361
         0         0         0
```

So one can pick the column 2 or 3 to make the matrix $R$ nonsingular and upper triangular (hence either the column 2 or 3 is a linear combination of the others).

Comment: I got my $R$ and $Q$, but I don't understand how I from that, find out which columns are linearly independent of the others?

Comment: When you say "the others", is there any way to see which columns? When you say either column 2 or 3 is a linear combination of the others?

Comment: Yes, column 2 is a linear combination of columns 1 and 3. Also, column 3 is a linear combination of columns 1 and 2.

Comment: if you swap column 1 and 2 in my question matrix $A$, how do I then find which are linear dependant? Thanks for the help so far by the way! I mean, I still don't fully understand, how do I from the $R$ matrix read out which are linearly independent?

Comment: Same approach, delete columns of $R$ until it becomes nonsingular upper triangular.

Comment: Everything in this answer is helpful except the black/red X diagram.  I have no idea what matrix that refers to.  But very valuable advice here is that the R matrix should be upper triangular and SQUARE, so when it looks like the numerical example, you can see that deleting a column and then deleting the row of 0's results in an upper triangular 2x2 matrix. I'm not certain what this would look like if column 1 were linearly dependent, or whether removing column 3 from R is necessarily same as removing 3rd column from input data.